# Difficulty updating e-mail body in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, ip

Guys I'm new to python but I made the code below with help of various websites and its working but the issue is its sending separate mails for each ip addresses in sites list. Help me construct mail body with all ip addresses.

**ping.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib
import pyping
from conf import settings, sites
import time
import datetime

"""Sends an e-mail to the specified recipient."""
sender = settings["monitor_email"]
recipient = settings["recipient_email"]
subject = settings["email_subject"]
headers = ["From: " + sender,
        "Subject: " + subject,
        "To: " + recipient,
        "MIME-Version: 1.0",
        "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
session = smtplib.SMTP(settings["monitor_server"], settings["monitor_server_port"])
session.ehlo()
session.login(settings["monitor_email"], settings["monitor_password"])
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for site in sites:
checker = pyping.ping(site)
# The site status changed from it's last value, so send an email

if checker.ret_code == 0:

        # The site is UP
        body = "%s This Server is up %s" % (site, st)
        session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
else:
        # The site is Down
        body = "%s This Server is down %s" % (site, st)
        session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)

session.quit()
```

**This is my conf.py**

```
sites = (
"192.168.1.1",
"192.168.2.1",
"192.168.3.1",
)

settings = {
"recipient_email": 'tomail@domain.com',
"monitor_email": 'frommail@domain.com',
"monitor_password": 'password',

# Leave as it is to use gmail as the server
"monitor_server": 'frommail@domain.com',
"monitor_server_port": 587,

# Optional Settings
"email_subject": 'Server Monitor Alert'
}
```

**I'm getting output as:**

Server Monitor Alert

192.168.1.1 This server is up at 2018-04-21

This mail comes successfully to tomail@domain.com  but  not in a single mail for three ip's it sends three mails with each ip address. Pls help me to send all ip status listed in sites in a single mail.

Comment: Keep data you want to send, and then send the email outside of the loop.

Comment: could you rewrite the code to that pls... I'm trying to keep both up and down server in same mail.

Comment: I'll post an example as an answer.

Comment: Python 2 is almost dead. You should spend your time learning Python 3.

Comment: yeah i'm getting this error on python 3.6.5                             
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ping test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyping
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyping\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from core import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'  but not in 2.7 version why this error occurs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
temp = []

for site in sites:
    checker = pyping.ping(site)
    # The site status changed from it's last value, so send an email

    if checker.ret_code == 0:
        # The site is UP
        body = "%s This Server is up %s" % (site, st)
        temp.append(body)
    else:
        # The site is Down
        body = "%s This Server is down %s" % (site, st)
        temp.append(body)

body = '\n'.join(temp)
session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
```

Comment: :) Buddy could you pls tell me why i'm geeting output as paragraph not in a list. New line not working

Comment: Did you try: `body = '\r\n'.join(temp)`?

Comment: If you're sending HTML then it should be `<br>` for newline.